# How to create objects using the factory constructor?

Tags: json, list, dictionary, flutter

I have converted my json data using https://app.quicktype.io/ and here is the result

```
import 'dart:convert';

LoginRespon loginResponFromJson(String str) => LoginRespon.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginResponToJson(LoginRespon data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginRespon {
    String status;
    Data data;

    LoginRespon({
        this.status,
        this.data,
    });

    factory LoginRespon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginRespon(
        status: json["status"],
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "data": data.toJson(),
    };
}

class Data {
    String resource;
    String unit;
    Data({
        this.resource,
        this.unit,
    });

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        resource: json["resource"],
        unit: json["unit"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "resource": resource,
        "unit": unit,
    };
}
```

and here is my original json data...before I do convert

```
{
  "status":200,
  "data":{
     "resource":"abc",
     "unit":"a"
}
}
```

I want to define each value in my json data using `LoginRespon` model... and I am doing this

```
List<LoginRespon> mydata = [];
Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
mydata.add(LoginRespon(
              status: res['status'],
              pesan: res['pesan'],
              resources:...?
              unit:...?
              ));
```

by using that code I am confused how to call `resources` and `unit` inside `res[data]`... is there a way to call value of `resources` and `unit` because they are in object inside object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have factory constructor made for the LoginRespon class then why are you passing these named parameters?

You can directly use your factory constructor and pass the decoded response. Eg. as follows:

```
Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response.body);
mydata.add(
   LoginRespon.fromJson(res);
);
```

Your factory will take care of passing correct values to the variables as you have declared in the .fromJson method of the LoginRespon class.

If you did not have factory constructor set up, then you would have to create objects of LoginRespon the way you have created in this code sample, that is by passing values to the named parameters and that would work, but even then you would not be able to pass the values to variables `resource` and `unit` as they does not exist in the class declaration and you would have to pass a `Data` object instead (Which contain values of `resource` and `unit` respectively).

Comment: I have tried it and I am getting error that say ```The named parameter 'resources' isn't defined.``` is there another way since ```resources``` is inside object of object

Comment: Okay, I just viewed your LoginRespon class and it doesnt even have the field called resource and unit, It has a field for Data, hence either change that instance variable or pass Data object to it instead of resources and unit!

Comment: yes... resources and unit are inside class of  ```Data```.... is there something that I should add?

Comment: I have tried it by passing a ```Data``` object Which contain values of resource and unit... thank you very much for your explanation and solution

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just nest it

```
res['data']['resource']

mydata.add(LoginRespon(
          status: res['status'],
          pesan: res['pesan'],
          resources:res['data']['resource']
          unit:res['data']['unit']
          ));
```

Comment: I have tried it... but the parameter ```resources``` always not defined.. is there another way since resources and unit is inside class of ```Data```

Comment: It will be undefined until you have any parameter with resource name.